# Footnote-numbers in the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, footnotes

After I finally made it that my figures can be used with a footnote, so I can write where I got the figure from I have the problem, that each entry in my list of figures on the last page gets a number which looks like a footnote. There are no footnotes on that page and the numbers continue from the previous real footnotes. It looks like that for each entry: [image]

I wouldn't mind if I just could delete the numbers later with Adobe Acrobat Pro, but unfortunately I don't have the necessary system font, although I thought I installed all LaTex fonts already. If anybody has a solution either for the actual problem or for my attempt of a workaround, I'd be very grateful.

I am using the usualy \listoffigures command, to list the figures at the last page. I am also using this command, to fix some footnote issues: \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000. The footnotes in my figures didn't work until I made them like that:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.png}
\caption{footnoteText\protect\footnotemark.}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{footnoteText. Available under \url{http://nowhere.com}, seen on 16. Januar 2014.}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the footnote mark to be replicated in the List of Figures, you have to use the optional argument in `\caption`, that is you have to substitute something like

```
\caption{captionText\footnotemark.}
```

with

```
\caption[captionText]{captionText\footnotemark.}
```

In this way, the contents of the optional argument will be printed in the LoF instead of the one in the mandatory argument.

To automate this, you can define a new command `\footcaption`

```
\newcommand{\footcaption}[1]{\caption[#1]{#1\footnotemark.}}
```

and use

```
\footcaption{captionText}
```

instead of writing

```
\caption[captionText]{captionText\footnotemark.}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the option demo in your document

\newcommand{\footcaption}[1]{\caption[#1]{#1\footnotemark.}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.png}
\footcaption{captionText}
\end{figure}
\footnotetext{footnoteText. Available under \url{http://nowhere.com}, seen on 16. Januar 2014.}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @UserSoUndSo Glad to help :-)